# Data that arrives while processing select()

Tags: network-programming

I'm using the select() call in my application in the same way as it is used here:
beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c

That is, I am calling select(), looping through all the file descriptors to process the data and then calling select() again. However, I'm wondering what happens to data that arrives while I am looping through and processing the data? Would select() return immediately, or would it wait until it sees new data?

The core of the question is, does select immediately return when there's available (old) data to recv(), or does it wait for new data to arrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's data available, select() returns immediately. It doesn't wait for more data to arrive. If there's no data then it blocks and waits.

In a way this has to be true, because file descriptors with the O_NONBLOCK flag will never block, yet select() must still work.

Comment: I did some more digging and people are saying select is level-triggered, not edge-triggered. Was this basically what I was referring to?

Answer (score 1):

`select` informs you if there is data to be read (in this case) on the socket. It does not care *when* it arrived, only *if* it's there.

So you will get a return indication from `select` regardless. In a similar manner, you may find that if you're notified on a socket when it has 5 bytes, and another 5 bytes appear between the `select` returning and you calling `read`. In that case, you get 10 bytes but that's fine. It won't "carry" those 5 bytes over to the next `select`.